Cancel process when loading data with Livewire
I am using Migrations to implement a code-first Approach in my Project. My project has multiple libraries. I need EF dependencies in my startup project to make migrations from another library. Is there any way to configure it so my migrations are limited to the library instead of providing an output directory in CLI?
ErrorMsg
